# Mark as executable

Tags: executable, elementary-os

I'm using Elementary OS. How do I mark a .jar file as executable. I do have JDK installed, but I get an error saying it isn't marked as executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either open a terminal and run

```
chmod +x yourfile.jar
```

or right-click the file in the file manager, open the `Properties` window, switch to the `Permissions` tab and check the `Execute` box in the `Owner:` row.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: At least that's the way it works in Nautilus/Files (GNOME's default file manager) which Pantheon's Files seems to be resembling quite closely.</sup>

---

You could also avoid the need to mark it as executable by using the Java executable to invoke it:

```
java -jar yourfile.jar
```

Comment: I tried using nautilus to go to properties and check the box with execute but the second after I check it, it unchecks by itself,which is really wired....

Comment: Have you tried setting it using `chmod` and checking if it persists?

Comment: I managed to run it with chmod eventually...Thank you!